# How to use regular 3rd party js libs with Jhipster 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster

I'm using Jhipster 4 with Angular 2 and need to use a 3rd party lib in my project, however the library is no on npm and doesn't have an .d.ts file. I need to include directly the js.
Import inside vendor.ts works for libraries installed via npm but won't work with my js, how can I use this file in my project?

Answer (score 7):

I am also trying to figure this out right now.. I actually couldn't get libraries installed via yarn to work by importing them in the vendor.ts file either though..

My current workaround (...until I can figure out the correct way to do this) was to copy the .js files I needed into src/main/webapp/content/js/ and reference it from webpack.common.js in the CopyWebpackPlugin plugin:

Under plugins in webpack.common.js, I added an entry to CopyWebpackPlugin:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js', to: 'core-js-shim.min.js' },
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist', to: 'swagger-ui/dist' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/', to: 'swagger-ui' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/i18n', to: 'i18n' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/content/js/FooLib.js', to: 'FooLib.js'}
]),
```

And then added an import to the webapp/index.html

```
    <script src='FooLib.js'></script>
```

And then declared it in the component that I was using it with:

```
declare var Foo: any;
```

Comment: it's works without declaring Foo variable. You can also import the entire folder like that : { from: './src/main/webapp/content/js/', to: 'content/js/'}. And then declare the script by importing the js files (<script type="application/javascript" src="content/js/yourScript.js"></script>)

Comment: Hi David, I cant thank you more for this work around. Did you stumble upon another clean solution?

I hate MDB now for being incompatible with JHipster :)

Answer (score 0):

While it's less than ideal, you can just use the plain-old-js. Link it as you would normally in the `index.html`, and then in any TypeScript code that you need to use it put a `declare` of the library at the top of the file. So, for example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare myAwesomeJsLibrary: any;

@Component(/* brevity*/)
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    myAwesomeJsLibrary.doSomethingAwesome();
  }
}
```

It doesn't give you any kind of autocompletion, of course, but you can always create your own interfaces and d.ts files for it if you *really* want. This way you can at least get it working.

Comment: But the case is that Jhipster uses webpack, the recomendation is to import the js inside the vendor.ts. I did that and tried to declare the libary but I get undefined when I try to use it. I guess it is not getting included in the index.html

Comment: That's interesting. Try link it directly in the index.html and see if it makes a difference? That might help diagnose the issue - ie: is it with the vendor.ts or with the declare.

Comment: Linking it directly in the index.html I'm not able to load the correct location of the js. The webpack creates a microserver that runs on the port 9090 and uses the auto reload, so it doesn't get the js that was added directly into the index